# Android material libraries

Tags: android

In my android project, there are no material library references in gradle, but i can use a classes from it, for example:

**com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior**
**com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment**

1. Which dependencies (standard libraries) include the com.google.android.material?

Why I can use classes from com.google.android.material with now reference to

**implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:XXX'**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Gradle `dependencyInsight` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:identifying_reason_dependency_selection) to answer this question. The command will look something like this:

```
./gradlew app:dependencyInsight --configuration debugRuntimeClasspath --dependency "com.google.android.material:material"
```

This will output a tree that shows which library is bringing Material Components along with it. Something like this:

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0 -> 1.3.0
\--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding3:rxbinding-material:3.1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the help